# iptables - rule to block all other incoming traffic except ssh

Tags: ssh, iptables

I currently have the following rules to allow connections to my SSH server on port 2233:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2233 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 2233 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

However, I now need to write a rule that blocks all other incoming traffic apart from the incoming traffic to the SSH on port 2233. I also need to enable logging for all other blocked traffic to be labelled as "BLOCKED TRAFFIC >"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If there is something wrong with the answer I provided to your previous question about this, then please say so there, and I'll edit the answer accordingly, if I am able. Don't start a new question. That answer took considerable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "BLOCKED TRAFFIC > " --log-level 4
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Packets not matched by previous ACCEPTs (or DROPs) will be processed and so get LOGged and then DROPped...